# How do you create taxi edges between parent nodes?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to create an edge between two parent nodes using `'curve-style': 'taxi'`. Unfortunately, edges between parent nodes don't seem to turn at right angles and generally route themselves very erratically.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // on dom ready

  // photos from flickr with creative commons license

  var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
      .style({
        'height': 80,
        'width': 80,
        'background-fit': 'cover',
        'border-color': '#000',
        'border-width': 3,
        'border-opacity': 0.5
      })
      .selector('.eating')
      .style({
        'border-color': 'red'
      })
      .selector('.eater')
      .style({
        'border-width': 9
      })
      .selector('edge')
      .style({
        'width': 6,
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'line-color': '#ffaaaa',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ffaaaa',
        'curve-style': 'taxi'
      })
      .selector('#bird')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7272/7633179468_3e19e45a0c_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#cat')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1261/1413379559_412a540d29_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#ladybug')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3063/2751740612_af11fb090b_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#aphid')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8316/8003798443_32d01257c8_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#rose')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5109/5817854163_eaccd688f5_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#grasshopper')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6098/6224655456_f4c3c98589_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#plant')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/231/524893064_f49a4d1d10_z.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#wheat')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2660/3715569167_7e978e8319_b.jpg'
      }),

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'cat',
            parent: 'bird'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'bird'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'ladybug'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'aphid'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'rose'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'grasshopper'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'plant'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'wheat'
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: 'cat',
            target: 'bird'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'bird',
            target: 'ladybug'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'bird',
            target: 'grasshopper'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'grasshopper',
            target: 'plant'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'grasshopper',
            target: 'wheat'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'ladybug',
            target: 'aphid'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'aphid',
            target: 'rose'
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    layout: {
      name: 'breadthfirst',
      directed: true
    }
  }); // cy init


}); // on dom ready
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <title>Images</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to get taxi edges to behave the same way they do between non-parent nodes?

Comment: Thanks for providing code, please post that code in future questions directly in your post and not as a link. That way, the link will expire one day but the question can still be answered/viewed. Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a weired layout behaviour in the [breadthfirst layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/breadthfirst). When using compound nodes in breadthfirst, it seems that the layout can't handle inner nodes that well, so the outer edges are not really bfs edges (bonding together), but rather two seperate bfs edges (not bonding). In order to get the `'curve-style': 'taxi'` to work, there is one simple but dumb way I think. Unfortunately, edges between parent nodes can't seem to turn at the right angles, so we have to make the bfs layout without the child nodes and add them afterwards (this is a stupid hack, but it works if you save all child nodes and add them afterwards:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // on dom ready

  // photos from flickr with creative commons license

  var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
      .style({
        'height': 80,
        'width': 80,
        'background-fit': 'cover',
        'border-color': '#000',
        'border-width': 3,
        'border-opacity': 0.5
      })
      .selector('.eating')
      .style({
        'border-color': 'red'
      })
      .selector('.eater')
      .style({
        'border-width': 9
      })
      .selector('edge')
      .style({
        "curve-style": "taxi",
        "taxi-direction": "downward",
        "taxi-turn": 20,
        "taxi-turn-min-distance": 5
      })
      .selector('#bird')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7272/7633179468_3e19e45a0c_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#cat')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1261/1413379559_412a540d29_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#ladybug')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3063/2751740612_af11fb090b_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#aphid')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8316/8003798443_32d01257c8_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#rose')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5109/5817854163_eaccd688f5_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#grasshopper')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6098/6224655456_f4c3c98589_b.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#plant')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/231/524893064_f49a4d1d10_z.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#wheat')
      .style({
        'background-image': 'https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2660/3715569167_7e978e8319_b.jpg'
      }),

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'bird'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'ladybug'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'aphid'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'rose'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'grasshopper'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'plant'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'wheat'
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: 'bird',
            target: 'ladybug'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'bird',
            target: 'grasshopper'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'grasshopper',
            target: 'plant'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'grasshopper',
            target: 'wheat'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'ladybug',
            target: 'aphid'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'aphid',
            target: 'rose'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    layout: {
      name: 'breadthfirst',
      directed: true
    }
  }); // cy init

  cy.ready(function() {
    cy.ready(function() {
      cy.add({
        data: {
          id: 'cat',
          parent: 'bird'
        }
      });
    });
  });

}); // on dom ready
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <title>Images</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I added a couple of lines in the css section of cytoscape, also the cy.ready() part at the end of the js file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to work at first, but then reverts to the broken behavior if you select an edge. This problem happens across all layouts, not just breadthFirst. Taxi edges are pretty new so might be fixable. I've filed a bug report on github.

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the source code a bit and found that you can make this work as expected by setting the `target-endpoint` and `source-endpoint` edge style attributes to `outside-to-node`.

There's a bit of a funky behavior where the edge disappears when the parent nodes get too close. I found that setting `'edge-distances': 'node-position'` and `'taxi-turn-min-distance': '0px'` helped with that. Here is the full edge style for reference:

```
'curve-style': 'taxi',
'edge-distances': 'node-position',
'taxi-turn-min-distance': '0px',
'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve',
'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
'target-endpoint': 'outside-to-node',
'source-endpoint': 'outside-to-node'
```